# Issue connecting to remote SQL Server database through VPN

Tags: sql-server, linux, dbeaver, vpn

I need to connect to a remote SQL Server database of a client to do some syncing and other stuff. They use a VPN connection and have provided me the VPN address, RDP to SQL Server, username and password.

- VPN Address: *...
- RDP to SQL Server: ..**.* : 4001
- Username: *************gonal
- Password: **********
- DB name: IS_*****

What I managed to do was connect with a new VPN connection I created with the VPN address, username and password that were given to me.Worked fine on a linux and a windows machine.

The main issue I seem to be having is when I try establish a connection to their DB. I use DBeaver on Linux and HeidiSQL on windows. Both give me errors, see below:

DBeaver (Linux):

[image: dbeaver]

HeidiSQL (Windows):

[image]

Is there something I am missing? I'm trying everything and would appreciate any help at all. Could it be a firewall issue? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure they haven't just given you access to RDP onto the box? To me, it looks that way seeing as they've given you a "RDP address". Why not ask the client? Can you actually ping the SQL Server box when you are VPNed? (pings might even be firewalled off)

Comment: Although you use a VPN, perhaps some ports are not allowed though the VPN connection.

Answer (score 1):

I'm speculating that since you were given RDP access and a username/account to the database server, the security credentials in question are Active Directory credentials.

DBeaver on Linux likely cannot use AD credentials (unless the environment taps into AD for authentication on Linux, in which case this isn't your issue).  I don't know if trying to authenticate via SQL Authentication using AD Credentials will throw the error you've provided, but it may be the cause.  I don't use DBeaver, so again this is just speculation.

HeidiSQL requires that you check the box next to *Use Windows authentication* as shown below:

[image]

Your screenshot covers up this area of the window so I haven't an idea if you're using this option or not.  Regardless, the caveat here is that that the Windows machine you are running HeidiSQL on has to be on the domain in question, and you need to have logged into said machine using the RDP credentials provided to you.  Basically, if you're using a Windows machine from DomainA, VPN into DomainB, and then run HeidiSQL and check this box, you're still going to get an error authenticating because it's using the authentication token created by the account used to log into the machine on DomainA and not the account needed to log into DomainB.

Again, the errors you're showing don't necessarily mean this is your issue, but it *could* be one reason why you're not able to connect remotely.

To start troubleshooting differently, I suggest you RDP to the server with a client that supports NLA/TLS connections (e.g. authentication occurs before an RDP session is opened) and see if you can log into SQL Server locally on the server.  If you can log in locally, start checking [other potential issues for remote connection issues](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sql_protocols/2008/04/30/steps-to-troubleshoot-sql-connectivity-issues/) and go from there.

If you provide more context in your question, I'll be happy to modify my answer accordingly as well.